# How to call AccountController's IsRegisterComplete Method from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I call the `IsRegisterComplete` method in `AccountController` from another ASP.NET MVC controller?

I am trying to do it like this:

```
TempData["TempDataRegistrationDetails"] = TempData["RegistrationDetails"];
TempData["Result"] = result;
return RedirectToAction("IsRegisterComplete ", "Account", new { Area = "Project.Presentation" });
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? What happens? Errors?

Comment: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Comment: Can you post the RouteConfig and also your project structure.

Comment: If you definitely have an `IsRegisterComplete` action in the `Account` controller then it could be the `Area = "Project.Presentation"` part of the redirect that is causing the error.

Comment: @scgough Both are in different project , is that a problem?

Comment: @ivan
`
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
`

Comment: @RaviPrakash I'd say that's definitely the issue. I take it you have 2 projects within the one solution? I have to say I've never had to redirect in this way (cross project). I'm guessing it can't be done like that though. You'd have to reference the full URL (`return Redirect("http://[otherproject_domain]/account/isreistercomplete");`)

Comment: @scgough
yes, it's in one solution and 2 different projects.
But what if I have to send data along with that?

Comment: @RaviPrakash ok, if you have to GET call that URL then you can add `?querystring=123` data to the call. If you need to POST to it then you can do this from the View (using jQuery for instance) or server side with `HttpClient` (for example). With POST, you would wait for a response to show success/fail then direct the user accordingly on your starting project.